# late row lookup issue with Limit and Offset

Tags: mysql

I want to make select query with limits and offsets and I use an example from this article

https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/

but I always get data only for one id from my table and have 1000 rows.

What is a problem with my query?
For example:

- id 57 name John;
- id 57 name John;

And so on...

```
SELECT d.id, drivers 
FROM ( SELECT id FROM drivers LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000) ds
JOIN drivers d ON d.id = ds.id;
```

Comment: `OFFSET 1000` will return the 1000th record onward only. Remove that to get the first 1000 records.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless (I bet @Quassnoi has an ORDER BY clause)

Comment: I get  the same issue with OFFSET 0

Comment: Add ORDER BY, but still get only one id `SELECT d.id, drivers FROM ( SELECT id FROM drivers ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0) ds
 JOIN drivers d ON d.id = ds.id ORDER BY d.id;`

Answer (score 0):

As per the reference blog your query should contain `order by desc` so the query will be as

```
SELECT d.id, drivers 
FROM ( SELECT id FROM drivers ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000) ds
JOIN drivers d ON d.id = ds.id;
```